# Qt Multi-map with different types linked to one key

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently in concept phase for setting up the model of a MVC in Qt5.

I would like to provide a method to adjust the header of `QAbstractTableModel`. This method should accept a single variable to define label of the header plus the related role, which consists of the following map structure:

- **[Key of type `int`]**
- Containing data:

  - **[Data of type `int`]**
  - **[Data of type `QString`]**

So something like this: `QMultiTypeMap( const QMap<Key, T1, T2> & other )`.
This is quite similar to `QMultiMap( const QMap<Key, T1> & other )`, except of the fact that I would need different types as values (T1 and T2).

Is there any possibility to realize this in elegant-coded way using Qt framework? I thought about using QHash nested inside a QMap but found that not so elegant (as I do not want to have a key-lookup behaviour nested in a key-pair structure).

Thank you for your ideas/knowledge.

Comment: Do you need both the int and QString at once? If you want just one, you can use [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant.html), it acts like a union.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `QPair` as the value type of `QMultiMap`:

```
QMultiMap<int, QPair<int, QString> > map;
```